# Validating numbered variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-4.0, indirection

I am writing a script to generate a text file, based on user-provided variable values. The variables are provided through another application and they come into Windows as environmental variables.

So I have the following:

```
[hashtable]$variables = @{InstallPath = $env:InstallPath; ADBaseOUValue1 = $env:ADBaseOUValue1; ADBaseOUValue2 = $env:ADBaseOUValue2; LDAPQueryValue1 = $env:LDAPQueryValue1; LDAPQueryValue2 = $env:LDAPQueryValue2}
```

This hash table is truncated, the user can define up to 15 ADBaseOUs and 15 LDAP queries and there are other variables provided, but none of them are numbered.

Now I need to validate the data.

1. I need to make sure that ADBaseOUValue1 and LDAPQueryValue1 are not null
2. I need to make sure that ADBaseOUValue1 matches a regex pattern
3. I need to make sure that, if LDAPQueryValue1 has ampersands (&) not follwed by "amp;", that I replace them
4. Then I need to make both check 2 and 3, for any ADBaseOUValue# and LDAPQueryValue# that the user has provided.

I am doing data validation on the other variables (e.g. $env:InstallPath), to make sure they are not null and have the expected types of data.

In variables $env:ADBaseOUValue2 through 15 and $env:LDAPQueryValue2 through 15, how would I:

1. Define the variable name when doing the "If" check against its regex
2. Define the variable name when doing the "replace" of "&"

Once the variables are validated, the values will go into a Here String like:

```
<setting name="ADBaseOU1" serializeAs="String">
    <value>$env:ADBaseOUValue1</value>
</setting>
<setting name="ADBaseOU2" serializeAs="String">
    <value>$env:ADBaseOUValue2</value>
</setting>
```

Thanks, here is what I have right now (for the validation part):

```
Switch ($variables.GetEnumerator()) {
    {($_.Name -eq "ADBaseOUValue1") -and ($_.Value -ne $null)} {
        If ($env:ADBaseOUValue1 -notmatch $ldapUrlRegex) {
            Write-Host ("{0}: The variable `"{1}`" was not a valid LDAP URL. Please re-run the script and provide a valid value for the variable." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

            $variableErrorCount++
        }
    }
    {($_.Name -eq "ADBaseOUValue1") -and ($_.Value -eq $null)} {
        If ($env:ADBaseOUValue1 -notmatch $ldapUrlRegex) {
            Write-Host ("{0}: The variable `"{1}`" was null. Please re-run the script and provide a value for the variable." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

            $variableErrorCount++
        }
    }
    {($_.Name -match "ADBaseOUValue(\d+)$") -and ($_.Name -ne "ADBaseOUValue1") -and ($_.Value -ne $null)} {
        If ($env:ADBaseOUValue1 -notmatch $ldapUrlRegex) {
            Write-Host ("{0}: The variable `"{1}`" was not a valid LDAP URL. Please re-run the script and provide a valid value for the variable." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

            $variableErrorCount++
        }
    }
    {($_.Name -eq "LDAPQueryValue1") -and ($_.Value -ne $null)} {
        If ($env:LDAPQueryValue1 -notmatch "&amp;") {
            Write-Host ("{0}: Replacing `"&`" with `"&amp;`" in {1}." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

            $env:LDAPQueryValue1 = $env:LDAPQueryValue1.Replace("&", "&amp;")
        }
    }
    {($_.Name -eq "LDAPQueryValue1") -and ($_.Value -eq $null)} {
        If ($env:ADBaseOUValue1 -notmatch $ldapUrlRegex) {
            Write-Host ("{0}: The variable `"{1}`" was null. Please re-run the script and provide a value for the variable." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

            $variableErrorCount++
        }
    }
    {($_.Name -match "LDAPQueryValue(\d+)$") -and ($_.Name -ne "LDAPQueryValue1") -and ($_.Value -ne $null)} {
        If ($env:??? -notmatch "&amp;") {
            Write-Host ("{0}: Replacing `"&`" with `"&amp;`" in {1}." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

            $env:??? = $env:???.Replace("&", "&amp;")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting question, but it could be made much more focused to benefit future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is *variable indirection*, i.e. to **access an environment variable *indirectly*, via a name stored in a *another variable***; e.g.:

```
$env:Foo = 'bar' # sample env. var.

$varName = 'Foo' # the name of that env. var to use for indirect access

# To GET the value, via PS drive Env:
Get-Content Env:$varName # same as: $env:Foo

# To SET the value:
Set-Content Env:$varName 'new value' # same as: $env:Foo = 'new value'
```

In the context of your command:

```
# ...

{$_.Name -match "LDAPQueryValue(\d+)$") -and ($_.Name -ne "LDAPQueryValue1") -and ($_.Value -ne $null)} {
  $currVal = Get-Content Env:$($_.Name)
  If ($currVal -notmatch "&amp;") {
      Write-Host ("{0}: Replacing `"&`" with `"&amp;`" in {1}." -f (Get-Date -Format s), $_.Name)

      Set-Content Env:$($_.Name) $currVal.Replace("&", "&amp;")
  }
}

# ...
```

See also the following conceptual help topics:

- [about_Environment_Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider)
- [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables)